# Multinomial cumulative logit

Tags: st.statistics

I have some difficulties on how to come from equation (2) to equation (3), can anyone help me with this problem?

It's the multinomial distribution which is written as the exponential family of distributions, and the aim is to find the cumulative link function.

\begin{align}
f(y_1, y_2, \ldots y_L; \theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots, \theta_L) &= \frac{n!}{y_1! \cdot y_2! \cdot \ldots \cdot y_{L}!} \cdot \theta_1^{y_1}\cdot \theta_2^{y_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot \theta_{L}^{y_{L}} \ \ \mbox{when} \ \ \sum_{l=1}^{L} y_l = n \\ 
& =\frac{n!}{y_1! \cdot y_2! \cdot \ldots \cdot y_{L}!} \cdot \exp{\Bigg\{y_1 \cdot y_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot y_{L} \cdot \sum_{l=1}^{L} \ln{\Big(\theta_l \Big)}\Bigg\}} (2)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_L; \theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots, \theta_L)&= \frac{n!}{\prod_{l=1}^{L} y_l !} \cdot \exp{\Bigg\{\sum_{l=1}^{L-1} y_l \cdot \\ \ln{\Big(\theta_l\Big)} + (1-\sum_{l=1}^{L-1} y_l) \cdot \ln{\Big(1- \sum_{l=1}^{L-1}\theta_l \Big)}\Bigg\}} (3)
\end{align}

Thanks in advance.